# How to select value from radio button while sending data to an email

Tags: php, html

Its an HTML site using php to make the mail function work

HTML codes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6">
        <div class="radion-btn-blk">
            <label class="container-rd">Option 1
                <input type="radio" id="Option1" name="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6">
        <div class="radion-btn-blk">
            <label class="container-rd">Option 2
                <input type="radio" id="Option2" name="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Sending data to email on submit**

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Event: ".$_POST["radio"]."\r\n";

    mail($ToEmail, $subject, $MESSAGE_BODY) or die("Failure");
}
```

The output I get is

```
Event: on
```

Can you tell me where i have gone wrong

I want the output (the selection that is checked) to be either Option 1  or Option 2

Comment: add value to the radio. `value=option1value`

Comment: why not `value="something"` ??

Answer (score 0):

You should set value="your value" for radio.

```
<div class="radion-btn-blk">
            <label class="container-rd">Option 2
                <input type="radio" id="Option2" name="radio" value="option2">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: so that you should set option to value